# Mongo lookup very slow when using a pipeline and field missing from some entries

Tags: mongodb

The following query is very fast

```
[{
    $match: {
        "deleted": {"$ne": true},
        "userId": {$exists: false}
    }
}, {
    $limit: 300
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'userId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user'
    }
}, {
    $count: 'count'
}]
```

But this one is very slow, well in my case I get

> Error in $cursor stage :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit

for 300 but works for a few

```
[
  {$match: {
    "deleted": {"$ne": true},
    "userId": {$exists: false}
  }}, 
  {$limit: 300}, 
  {$lookup: {
  "from": "users",
  "let": {
    "userId": "$userId"
  },
  "pipeline": [{
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": ["$_id", "$$userId"]
      }
    },
  }],
  "as": "user"
  }}, 
  {$count: 'count'}
]
```

I am using "userId": {$exists: false} just to prove how slow, normally userId exists most time but sometimes it doesn't and for cases when maybe it's 50% the query is very slow.

I already tried a sparse index and I am on mongo 4.2. Not sure but this might not be as slow on the latest mongo.

Any ideas on how to improve the speed of the query?

Thank you

NOTE: this is not the full query, I have another join and some projects in there, otherwise I would have used the first version.

Answer (score 0):

In this query there are 2 problems at least that i see

- If you have an index on `"userId"` make sure all documents have a `userId` value,
  add `null`, to enable the use of index (as far as i know, check for missing field => collscan)
- In MongoDB < 5, an index cant be used inside a `$lookup` with pipeline
  when `$expr` is used (and you can't avoid it if you want to compare with variable)

To fix it, if possible try those

- add the nulls instead of missing fields (if you have index on userId)
- change to simple `$lookup` (and do the changes after the lookup) or update to MongoDB 5

[Check this also](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-performance-with-null-vs-exists/108103/4) and [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-optimization/116047)

Comment: Thank you, thought so too, I need to use $expr otherwise I can use a $project to get only the fields I want. I think the best way would be to switch to simple $lookups and have a big $project at the end. Not ideal on the type of documents I am working with but better than having a slow query.